# How to get data from dynamic mongoID with aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

Here is have two collections

1. Product
2. individual Product stock (collectionname is like mongoID)

1.Product collection

```
db.getCollection("products").insert({ _id:"60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda",
"name":"mobile"
})
```

2 dynamicID collection

```
 db.getCollection("60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda").insert(
        { quantity:5,product:"60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda" } 
        )
```

My Query is like

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
        from: '_id',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'product',
        as: 'stocks'
        }
    }, 
    ])
```

Getting blank Array

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can't dynamically `lookup` collections.
The `from` field cannot be an expression and must be a string literal.

There is an open feature request for [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497.) however it seems it is very unlikely to happen:

> Thanks to everyone for voting and giving your input on this request. Currently, there are no plans for supporting variable `from' collection per document, that would require significant changes in the security and query optimization architectures.

Comment: Thanks for Repy 
Any other way to do this ??

Comment: I recommend you change the structure and not split all the products into different collections. but with the current structure you have to query twice to do so. ( which is also fine to do )

Answer (score 0):

Your second insert statement inserted into a collection called "60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda".  Your $lookup refers to a non-existent collection called "_id".  To make this work try this...

Insert into 2 collections...

```
db.getCollection("products").insert({
    _id:"60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda",
    "name":"mobile"
})
 
db.getCollection("inventoryStock").insert({
    quantity:5, 
    product:"60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda"
})
```

Run Aggregation...

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: 
        {
            from: 'inventoryStock',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'product',
            as: 'stocks'
        }
    }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda", "name" : "mobile", "stocks" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("60e0ffff1e165946802c244a"), "quantity" : 5, "product" : "60dcc2f4c8b03e500a019fda" } ] }
```